# Automatically grant ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to grant runtime permissions to my app automatically, for ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION. Like the Facebook messenger never ask you for ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION in runtime. I am wondering is there any way to grant permission automatically.

At the moment, I am using the following code to grant permission.

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && !Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            //If the draw over permission is not available open the settings screen
            //to grant the permission.
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        } //else
            //If permission is granted start floating widget service

Comment: `ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION` is not a permission. It is an `Intent` action. You cannot grant an `Intent` action as a permission.

Comment: I got it now, Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a way to automatically grant permissions. You need to target an API level below 23 and include the permission in the manifest.

Comment: YW. If this ends up being the solution can you please accept the answer.